# Greasemonkey script to refresh page until target string is found

Tags: javascript, strings, html, userscript

I've been working on this user script to hunt for a specific string in an HTML webpage with the goal of finding the time at which it appeared.  This feels needlessly complicated and I would like advice on how too condense and upgrade the code to more simply find the time.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           Magma Time Finder
// @namespace      Will.GG
// @description    Refreshes the page until target string is found
// @include        *www.website.com
// @include http://www.website.com
// @grant metadata
// ==/UserScript==
var strHTML = document.body.innerHTML;
var yourTime = new Date();
var count = 1;
if(strHTML.indexOf("Text to find here") < 0){
  alert(yourTime);

} else {

  var lastCheck = document.createElement("div");
  lastCheck.innerHTML = "Last Check: " + yourTime.toString();
  console.log('Iteration: ' + count);
  count++;
  var parent = document.getElementsByClassName("content")[0];
  parent.insertBefore(lastCheck, parent.children[1]);

  window.setTimeout(function(){window.location.reload() ;},300000) ;

} 
return;
```

Answer (score 2):

Right now, your code grabs *everything* HTML related in the document. However, from what I can tell, you only want to search the *text* on a webpage.

That being said, this code currently could potentially pick up a string that is embedded in the HTML code, but is not actually visible to the user on the screen.

To only grab the text, you can use either the `innerText` property of the `textContent` of the body:

```
var text = document.body.innerText || document.body.textContent;
```

Now, the `text` variable will contain all the text in the document, excluding the actual HTML code.

---

Now, I may be mistaken, but after some testing, it seems that `count` does not exist after the page resets. Therefore, you can just remove this variable and all interactions with it.

---

> ```
> window.setTimeout(function(){window.location.reload() ;},300000) ;
> ```

Where did that `300000` come from? You should declare a [constant at the top of your code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47882/what-is-a-magic-number-and-why-is-it-bad).

---

> ```
> return;
> ```

This is unnecessary and is confusing. This should be removed.

---

The `console.log`s seem to me that they were used for debugging, since they don't seem to be showing any important message to the user, and why would the user be looking in the console anyway?. These can be removed.

---

Now, this is what your code looks like:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           Magma Time Finder
// @namespace      Will.GG
// @description    Refreshes the page until target string is found
// @include        *www.website.com
// @include http://www.website.com
// @grant metadata
// ==/UserScript==

var FREQUENCY = 300000;

var text = document.body.innerHTMl || document.body.textContent;
var yourTime = new Date();

if (text.indexOf("Text to find here") < 0) {
    alert(yourTime);
} else {
    var lastCheck = document.createElement("div");
    lastCheck.innerHTML = "Last Check: " + yourTime.toString();
    var parent = document.getElementsByClassName("content")[0];
    parent.insertBefore(lastCheck, parent.children[1]);

    window.setTimeout(window.location.reload, FREQUENCY);
}
```

Comment: `window.setTimeout(window.location.reload, FREQUENCY)` will result in an error.  On chrome it's: "Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation"

Comment: @gilly3 You are correct. I edited that part out.